# Why is there a Segmentation Fault in this code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//create a struct to have model number and name and a pointer to next book
struct comp
{
    string nam;
    int mnum;
    comp* next; 
};

// define comp pointer to compPtr
typedef comp* compPtr;

int main()
{
    compPtr head = NULL;
    compPtr last = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        compPtr temp;
        temp->nam = "Dell";
        temp->mnum = 45215;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        compPtr temp1;
        temp1->nam = "Mac";
        temp1->mnum = 1255;
        temp1->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp1;
        last = temp1;
    }

    compPtr compnext;
    compnext = head;
    if (compnext == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"NO COMPUTERS";
    }
    else
    {
        while(compnext != NULL)
        {
            cout<<compnext->nam<<endl;
            cout<<compnext->mnum<<endl;
            compnext = compnext->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there a Segmentation Fault in this code?

Don't "hide" pointers behind a `typedef` -- it will only confuse you.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
comp *temp;          // Note: does not point *anywhere*.
temp->nam = "Dell";  // Dereferencing uninitialized pointer, undefined behavior,
                     // often crash.
```